# I'm having problems using beautiful soup to find <name></name> in an xml

Tags: xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get beautiful soup return  text  using beautifulsoup.name. But it just gives me [document] for a Beautiful Soup object. Any suggestions on how I can use Beautiful Soup to return  text  in an XML file?

```
import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
f = open(file)
soup = bsoup(f)
f.close()

f = soup.name

This code will return [document]


But I'm looking to for a function in beautiful soup to return:

<name>car</name>
```

Comment: Some code added. I'm a little new to coding so some the terms I use might be vague or awkward. Feel free to ask for more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Beautiful Soup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/beautifulsoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree) for Beautiful Soup 4,

I see

You want

```
import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
f = open(file)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
f.close()`
print(soup.find('name'))
```

For printing `<name>car</name>` or `print (soup.find('name').name)` for printing `car`.